# asmx web service via soap and i want to responce in json object in android

Tags: android, json, web-services, soap, asmx

I call the .asmx web service via soap and i want to responce in json object in android how it possible. My code is:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("email",s1);
        request.addProperty("password",s2);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        try {
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
            if(result != null){
                et_unm.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
            } else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.v("LOGIN::","Exception--->"+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
myThread.start();
```

Comment: When i run this exception is returned in log--> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT [ {  "email...@8:2 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40d45d08)

Comment: http://www.programmingrelief.com/1895834/Soap-Web-Service-And-Json-Responce-In-Android

Visit this link it may help you.!

Comment: In this line--->>>>>>>>HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL); Exception is generated-> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this post,

you can use built-in apache classes like HttpClient, HttpGet, HttpPost, etc. It is described here in this post.

> [How to Call ASMX Web service VIA JSON object in android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422643/how-to-call-asmx-web-service-via-json-object-in-anroid-application/21423807#comment32332934_21423807)