# When i get data from asmx webservice error occurs in android

Tags: android, json, web-services, soap

I have one problem.
My web-service returns JSON data and when i call it using SOAP then the exception is occurred. 
If i want to call using SOAP and get response in JSON object, if it possible.

In below line i get the exception.

> androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

Exception is:

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT [

Comment: What exception occured? please paste you exception here..

Comment: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT [

Comment: PLease help me.. I am trying this from last 3 days.

Comment: okay.. I think you are calling wrong url.. please post all METHOD_NAME,NAMESPACE,SOAP_ACTION

Comment: private static String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/login";    
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "login";

Comment: Have you checked this link ? http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-java-soap-web-service-access.html

Comment: @MehulRanpara,  Not Working. Same exception occured.

Comment: I think soap response only XML data, but in my web service use the json. So this problem is occurred.

Comment: @MehulRanpara when soap read text data like "[" then it occures exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use built-in apache classes like HttpClient, HttpGet, HttpPost, etc. It is described here in this post.

> [How to Call ASMX Web service VIA JSON object in android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422643/how-to-call-asmx-web-service-via-json-object-in-anroid-application/21423807#comment32332934_21423807)